# How make sure that singleton message driven bean processes one message at a time?

Tags: java, singleton, synchronized, message-driven-bean

How can I make sure that my singleton message driven bean processes one message at a time?

```
@Singleton
public class MyMdb implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Making the onMessage method synchronized doesn't work, as that causes this error:

`weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.ComplianceException: In EJB MyMdb, Enterprise Bean methods must not use thread synchronization primitives. The method named onMessage(javax.jms.Message) is synchronized.`

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle WebLogic Server you can use the Unit-Of-Order feature. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13727/uoo.htm official documentation to lean more. Messages with same Unit-Of-Order header will be processing one-then-one strongly.

Also you can add custome Work Manager to your EJB and set MinThreadConstraint and MaxThreadConstraint to one. All your messages will be processing one-then-one in one thread.

Comment: Any idea how to add the custom Work Manager please ?

Comment: Just add the following line <wls:work-manager><wls:name>CalculatorWorkManager</wls:name></wls:work-manager> to your EJB description (inside the wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean element) in the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that use of singleton is not as intended.
I believe @Singleton is meant for non-MDBs.
In fact, just implementing `MessageListener` is not enough to make an MDB.
You have to annotate your class as @MessageDriven, as well.

Instead of trying to make a singleton MDB, you might try to make your MDB (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpo.html), and then create a second EJB--not an MDB--as a true singleton.
You can control access to that, using singleton's concurrency annotations.
Then inject an 'instance' (really a proxy) of the new singleton into your MDB and have the MDB do all its processing through the singleton.

[Here is info on that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipsz/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

The EJB 3.1 spec
(http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf)
says in section 5.7.4 Non-reentrant Instances (in chapter 5 Message-Driven Bean Component Contract):

> The container must ensure that only one thread can be executing an
>   instance at any time.

Thus a singleton MDB always executes only one message at a time, and there's no need to configure this.